# Flexbox max-height percentage value somehow related to the parent container percentage value

Tags: css, flexbox

I have following flexbox [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/parawug/edit?html,css,output) which works. In the CSS I am setting the max-height of the transparant banner at 25%, in the output the image (flexbox container) is covered 50%, see here:

[image: here]

Why is that? I would expect it to be covered for 25%?

After some trial and error I notice that the 50% min-height of the image (the container for the banner) is somehow multiplied by the 50% I want to be covered, resulting in 25%. Still I do not get why this is...?

So in short: Why is the transparant banner cover 50% instead of 25%?

Comment: The way I read your code, you set the overlay to stretch the whole viewport height by doing `.overlay { height: 100vh; }`. You're now playing with the vh unit. Then setting `display: flex` will make it's children inherit this height. Then doing `.overlay .item-image { min-height: 50% }` will only set a minimun height, not altering it's actual height. Now when you set `.overlay .item-image .transparant-banner { max-height: 25%; }` it will be set to 25% of the height of `.overlay`, namely 25% of the viewport height, not 25% of the parent element.

Comment: Thanks. That's it. What confused me was a variation on this fiddle in which the overlay and the item-image were same height. Anyway, I get it now. If you put it as answer I can approve it.

Comment: Glad you solved it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agrm is right, the `100vh` is inherited to the childeren. To solve this and get expected behavior you need to not just set `min-height` to `50%` but also set `height` to `50%` (both in the parent-container, i.e. `.item-image`). Then the output will show a 25% coverage by the transparant banner.

This can be considered best practice as it will provide 'consistent layout behavior' in case there is suddenly just 1 div element (instead of two) in the viewport. This one element will then be stretched in height by flexbox to fullscreen height and the transparant banner will still cover it for 25%. Whereas in case of not setting the height on the parent-container I ended up with a banner which persisted its seize resulting in a too small banner height (12.5%) relative to the image.